# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Geopy'

Tags: python, geopy

I'm trying to install geopy and import it so that I can create a coordinate column for the data in my project.  I installed it using pip, as you can see it's located in the python 3.11 environment site packages.

[The library is installed as you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IknSa.png)

However, when running the jupyter cell that imports geopy in VSCode, I still get the ModuleNotFound error. I'm using the same python version as my interpreter.

[Here is the interpreter I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaDkM.png)

But i still get the error shown below:

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8Sdl.png)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Ive also tried creating a virtual environment and installing geopy from there. I get the same issue.

As requested heres the pip version I am using:
`pip 23.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)`

and the result of printing `sys.path()`:

`['/Users/abdelazimlokma/Documents/GitHub/ds-bu-sustainability-waste/spring23-team-1/data', '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python39.zip', '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9', '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '', '/Users/abdelazimlokma/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages', '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages', '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aeosa', '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/extensions', '/Users/abdelazimlokma/.ipython']`

Comment: Did you also activate the virtual environment before running the code? (Apparently not, given the "Here is the interpreter I am using" image)

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. Include them in the question text.

Comment: The image was taken before trying to create a virtual environment, I'm mainly trying to fix the issue with the base environment first

Comment: Each version of Python installed on your computer (including virtual environments) has a separate area for installing modules.  Your `pip` is apparently using a different version than your python interpreter.

Comment: Edit your question to include the output of this command `pip --version` and also this python code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: As John Gordon is pointing out, your first screenshot just means it is installed somewhere on your system which isn't necessarily where you Jupyter in VSCode is using. If you would like to try to get things working without sorting out the environment paths entirely and don't mind potentially installing this package another time on your machine, you can try issuing in a new cell inside Jupyter in VSCode the command `%pip install geopy`. Restart the kernel after it completes and then try the import again.

Comment: Thank you all for the help, for the sake of urgency I followed Wayne's solution, which worked. I appreciate the help :)